# OAUTH authentication with bigQueryR results in Unauthorized (HTTP 401) error

Tags: r, authentication, oauth, google-bigquery

I try to use `bigQueryR` with OAUTH authentication (I have my reasons not to use service key authentication).

As the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigQueryR/vignettes/bigQueryR.html) suggests I did the following and received an error:

```
> library(bigQueryR)
> bqr_auth()

Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
Error in oauth2.0_access_token(endpoint, app, code = code, user_params = user_params,  : 
Unauthorized (HTTP 401). Failed to get an access token.
In addition: Warning message:
In googleAuthR::gar_auto_auth(required_scopes, new_user = new_user,  :
travis_environment_var argument is now unsupported and does nothing
```

In this project I already used OAUTH successfully with `bigRQuery` (note, not `bigQueryR`), thus I already had a `.httr-oauth` file in my working directory.

I also tried to remove this file and then authenticate again. Same error. I also tried `bqr_auth(new_user = TRUE)` without success. With `googleAuthR::gar_auth(new_user = TRUE)` I get the same error as well.

I'd like to know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer by accident soon after posting the question. This is due to a bug in `bigQueryR`: https://github.com/cloudyr/bigQueryR/issues/45

The creator of the package suggests to use the service key authentication method until a fix is in place.

**EDIT -** creator of the package closed this issue. Hopefully solved now.